# How to load JSDs from multiple sources and create a java schema object?

Tags: java, json, jsonschema

I have a JSD named SampleRequestMessage.jsd . In this jsd i have a reference to another jsd SampleRequestMessageProperties.jsd as shown below

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "javaName": "SampleConfigureNodeRequestMessage",
  "description": "This message comes from sample-paqx and gets translated into Southbound version of this message",
  "_meta": {
     "message":"com.dell.cpsd.sample.configure.node.request",
     "version":"1.0"
  },
  "type" : "object",
  "id" : "**SampleRequestMessage.jsd**",
  "properties" : {
    "messageProperties" : {
      "type" : "object",
      "$ref" : "**SampleRequestMessageProperties.jsd**"
    },
    "endpointURL" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "userName" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "password" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  },
  "required":[
     "messageProperties",
     "endpointURL",
     "userName",
     "password"
  ]
}
```

I want the Schema object of this JSD so that I can validate it against a JSON. Now how can I load all the references of the Parent JSD.In this case it is SampleRequestMessageProperties.jsd. This JSD is pulled from one of the dependency jars. I may have to pull the referenced JSDs from multiple folders and create a Schema object for parent JSD. How can I do this? Please help

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "javaName": "SampleConfigureNodeRequestMessage",
  "description": "This message comes from sample-paqx and gets translated into Southbound version of this message",
  "_meta": {
     "message":"com.dell.cpsd.sample.configure.node.request",
     "version":"1.0"
  },"definitions": {
    "SampleRequestMessage": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "test": { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["test"]
    }
  },
  "type" : "object",
  "properties" : {
    "messageProperties" : {"$ref": "#/definitions/SampleRequestMessage"
    },
    "endpointURL" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "userName" : {
      "type" : "string"
    },
    "password" : {
      "type" : "string"
    }
  },
  "required":[
     "messageProperties",
     "endpointURL",
     "userName",
     "password"
  ]
}
```

This would validate the following json.

```
{
  "messageProperties": {"test": "hello"},
  "endpointURL":  "test.com",
    "userName": "test",
    "password": "secret"
  }
}
```

The definitions can also be in a external file. For more infos: [refer json schmea](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html)

Hope this helps